# Access a custom global variable on Woocommerce thankyou

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to set a global variable as a flag. I want to use that in the thankyou.php template to show a custom message when the ordered items are not in stock. It doesn't work.

My code in functions.php:

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
global $flag_custom_order;
$flag_custom_order=false;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
    $stock=$_product->get_stock_quantity();
    if ($stock <= '0') :
        $flag_custom_order=true;
    endif;    
}
```

In `thankyou.php` template i add this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As cart is emptied once other is placed, the value of `$flag_custom_order` variable will be always `false` on Order received (thankyou) page.

Instead you could use the following in your active theme's `functions.php` file *(that will save that as custom order meta data when order is placed, before data is saved)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_wc_checkout_create_order',  10, 2  );
function action_wc_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    $has_backordered_items = false;
    
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) { 
            if ( $cart_item['data']->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ) {
                $has_backordered_items = true;
                break;
            }    
        }
    }
    
    if( $has_backordered_items ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_has_backordered_items', $has_backordered_items );
    }
}
```

Then in your `thankyou.php` template file you will use the following *(as the `WC_Order` object exist)*:

```
<?php 
    if ( $order->get_meta('_has_backordered_items') ) {
        echo '<p>' . __("This order has backordered items.") . '</p>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to look into this. I added the code to my chid theme functions.php and to the thankyou.php. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AdrianP. Sorry there was a mistake, code updated… Try it again

Comment: I just changed _has_backorders to _is_backorder  on the thankyou page and now it works. Thank you!